# Google App Engine multiple regions

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible for my GAE to be balanced accross regions? Like US and Europe.
https://cloud.google.com/about/locations/
Reading the link above it says that it scales automatically within or accross multi-regional locations.
What does that mean? Do I have to enable automatic scaling across regions? If so, how do I do that?
And secondly, if it does handle automatic scaling across regions, the choice one makes for `App engine location` when creating a new project, is that irrelevant for a Google App Engine instance?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Yon asked this question on [the mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-appengine/Upxbns9ZpAc), where it was answered. To reiterate what folks said there: App Engine is [automatically scaled across multiple regions](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/console/#create), but those regions are defined by Google. You'd have to set up another project to handle traffic in the EU, for example.

Comment: OK "set up another project to handle traffic in the EU" - Q then how balance the traffic?

Comment: I think this answer confuses more than it helps. GAE does not allow you to deploy an app into multiple regions. Consequently any question about load balancing a GAE app across multiple regions is nonsensical.

Comment: App Engine scales across *zones* (within a single region), not across multiple regions.

Answer (score 5):

See this from Google Groups: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/google-appengine/svMhwuFC5zk

The short answer today is no it cannot be accomplished in App Engine as is.

But, if you feel like hacking, it seems the above thread is suggesting setting up a load balancer to serve Compute Engine and then have these instances route to your "different" projects with App Engine deployed in your various regions (i.e. one deployment in a region per project). Seems like a mess, but possible.

There may be light at the end of the tunnel (eventually): https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/65039982

Answer (score 2):

You cannot change the region. Your app will be served from the region you chose when creating the app. Anyone can use the app, but users closer to the selected region will have lower latency.

While the App Engine service itself operates in multiple regions, an App Engine app is served from a single region. The app will, however, scale across multiple zones within that region.

See [App Engine Locations](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/locations) for more.

Comment: Q great - and how build appengine with loadbalancer? 

Comment: @BGBruno App Engine features a built-in load balancer which provides transparent L3 and L7 load balancing to applications.

Comment: It wouldn't be a very useful PaaS if it didn't include load balancing ;-) See https://cloud.google.com/solutions/architecture/webapp

Comment: App Engine is regional. Your resources exist in a single region.

Comment: sure that's why my first question within the topic "multiple region" - Q how build appengine with loadbalancer for multi region US-EU-ASIA ? 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177595/discussion-between-jarmod-and-bg-bruno).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a potential solution using HTTPS LB with [Serverless NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/setting-up-serverless-negs), Serverless NEG connects internal services directly without GCE. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/62660953/4185100