# What is the best approch to setup custom domain with static IP for AppEngine

Tags: google-app-engine

I had done an investigation on below

1. Adding custom domain through AppEngine settings - Doesn't seem to be static IP, it uses Google NS.
2. Setting up VM and run as a proxy - Seems to be convoluted method and security/maintenance overhead.
3. HTTPS load balancer with [internet NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/internet-neg-concepts) I am still investigating and it said

> You should do this when you want to serve content from an origin that is hosted outside of Google Cloud, and you want your external HTTP(S) load balancer to be the frontend.

Any suggesions/thoughts for this solution will be greatly appricated to chose right solution for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Static IP for AppEngine/Cloud Functions can be achieved by HTTPS Load Balancer with "Serverless Network End Group" backend.

LB also helps multi-region serving for AppEngine and other serverless components.

This is similar to [Internet NEG](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/setting-up-internet-negs) with HTTPS LB, serverless NEG can be mapped to Google internal services like Cloud run/CF, AppEngine. It was also possible to map multiple AppEngine services from the same GCP project.

I was able to gain early access to serverless NEG on my project and test on my side. I will update this post when Serverless NEG available for public access.

### Edit (7/7/2020): Serverless NEG is available in Beta now and is available for everyone to access, See

[Serverless network endpoint groups overview](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/serverless-neg-concepts)

[Setting up serverless NEGs](https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/negs/setting-up-serverless-negs)

Answer (score 0):

As you can see at [this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/kb/#static-ip) documentation, "App Engine does not currently provide a way to map static IP addresses to an application. In order to optimize the network path between an end user and an App Engine application, end users on different ISPs or geographic locations might use different IP addresses to access the same App Engine application". So, there is no way to set a static IP address to App Engine but you can use a use a pool of IP address. In the shared link, you can find the way to use ranges of IP address in App Engine. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54987500/google-app-engine-static-ip-address-custom-domain) other link, explain a bit more how to do it.

Comment: You are right, #1 mentioned in my questin found that. Google's NS gets new IP's from different geolocation.

Comment: Also, I cannot map to different GAE services URL running, if I use #1